# Wordpress Using an If statement inside a for loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to use an if statement to detect if the category page that is currently being viewed is from a category list being lifted from wordpress. I cant use a static list as this list is likely to change as the admin changes things.

```
<?php 
     $args = array(
         'orderby' => 'name',
         'parent' => 8,
         'taxonomy' => 'category'
     );
     $categories = get_categories( $args );
     foreach ( $categories as $category1 ) { ?>

     <?php if (is_category(<?php echo get_cat_name("$category1->term_id;"); ?>)) : ?>
         <p>This is the text to describe category A</p>
     <?php else : ?>
         <p>This is the text to describe category B</p>
     <?php endif; ?>  
}?>
```

This is what I have so far, it works if I use a static list but when I try and get the is category to work with the get_cat_name it gives me an error 500.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a 500 error because of this line:

```
<?php if (is_category(<?php echo get_cat_name("$category1->term_id;"); ?>)) : ?>
```

It should simply be:

```
<?php if (is_category(get_cat_name($category1->term_id))) : ?>
```

`echo` is used to send a string to the output buffer (in other words, to output the text to the browser). You don't need to `echo` values into another function. Additionally, when you pass a value to a function, you can send the variable (`$category1->term_id`) directly.

You also don't need to open a `<?php` tag when you haven't closed the previous tag.

Comment: also, you don't need quotes and semicolon here `"$category1->term_id;"`. instead use `$category1->term_id`

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan Good catch; updating the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.